# Laravel - valet 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel, https, laravel-valet, valet

I have a laravel project which was working fine in `http` with `php artisan serve`. But I was working on a project where I needed to implement Facebook Login API which requires call from `https`, for doing this I installed valet globally executed following command:

```
 valet link backend-laravel
 valet secure backend-laravel
```

Here is the screenshot of `valet links`
[image: valet links]

Now when i enter `https://backend-laravel.test` it shows `404 error`.

How can make it running? Is there something I missed?

Comment: run valet park from your project directory.

Comment: from inside the backend-laravel or outside. PS: dir name is backend-laravel

Comment: inside the backend-laravel

Comment: I executed the command and got following result `This directory has been added to Valet's paths.` but still the URL is showing 404. Do I need to restart some service ?

Comment: No try to run valet link backend-laravel from backend-laravel directory

Comment: @JinalSomaiya thanks it worked! Kindly post your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Run following commands from the root of your laravel projects directory:

```
valet park
valet link backend-laravel
```

Comment: I wish I would have seen this thread a few days ago. I did a fresh OS install to download and setup tools I use so that I can image my mac. I've done it several times now... 5 to be exact. Your comments above worked perfectly. I edited the answer to include the valet park which was discussed in comments to OP. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: You can run these commands in a directory containing multiple site directories. On my mac I use Sites folder to hold all of my projects. Run it in the directory you keep your sites in and it will serve all of them.

Comment: "from your project directory" seems wrong here. "from the root of your laravel projects" seems more correct, as per Prakash's answer

Answer (score 4):

naming convention for project directory should follow kabab case.

**correct :** backend-project

**incorrect :** backend_project

and hit "backend-project" in browser. by the way it will work for both directories backend-project and backend_project

Comment: This naming convention solved my problem! Changed my directory from snake case to kebab case and it's resolving fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should run:

```
valet park
```

In the main folder, where all the Laravel projects are stored, the project folders are located. To open a project in your browser, you should access it by using the URL format: "folder_name_inside_the_main_folder.test."

OR

You should run:

```
valet link
```

on your project folder and open foldername.test on the browser.

Hope it helps someone!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should run:

```
valet park
```

from your project folder to add it to Valet's paths.

Answer (score 1):

In my own case (Vanilla PHP project), `public` folder was the cause of my issue.

Inside my project folder, I have a public folder that houses all my assets.

Turns out the valet driver checks inside the public folder for `index.php` which makes sense because that's how Laravel is configured.

> So I had to rename the `public` folder that house all my assets to `assets`.

You can rename it to whatever you want.

Answer (score -2):

Try to reinstall valet
run `valet uninstall`
and
`valet install`